# react-apollo - how to set query variables from wrapped component?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

`react-apollo` provides the ability to convert component props to query variables:

```
<MyComponentWithData propsForQueryVariables={...} />
```

But I need start query with variables from wrapped component.

Something like:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   //...
   onReady() {
     // should be first request to server
     this.props.refetch({
       // variables here
     })
   }

   onFilterChanged() {
     this.props.refetch({
       // new variables here
     })
   }
}

const MyComponentWithData = graphql(QUERY, {
  options: {
    waitUntilComponentStartQuery: true
    // pollInterval:...
  },
  props({ data: { items, refetch } }) {
    return {
      items: items,
      refetch: refetch
    };
  }
})(MyComponent);
```

*UPDATE*

`QUERY` for `MyComponent` looks like

```
query getItems($filter: JSON!) {
 items(filter: $filter) {
  id
  name
 } 
}
```

`filter` is **not nullable**. So the first request should have valid variable `filter`, and this variable should be created in wrapped component.

Comment: using graphcool I was unable to get the filter to work, states that one cannot pass objects as children and such. Any ideas on where to go from there?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the parent props to the variables of the initial fetch in the graphql HoC, like this:

`ParentComponent.jsx`

```js
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

const ParentComponent = () => <ChildComponent filterPropValue="myDefaultFilterValue" />;

export default ParentComponent;
```

`ChildComponent.jsx`

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  refresh() {
    this.props.refetch({
      filter: 'mynewFilterValue'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>I am a child component with {this.props.items.length} items.</div>
    );
  }
}

export default graphql(MyQuery, {
  options: (props) => ({
    variables: {
      filter: props.filterPropValue
    }
  }),
  props: ({ data: { items, error, refetch }) => ({
    items,
    error,
    refetch
  })
})(ChildComponent);
```

Any subsequent refetches with new parameters can then be dealt with via `refetch()`.

Comment: I have a query like `query getItems($filter: JSON!) { items(filter: $filter) { id } }`. `filter` is **not nullable**. So firt request, should have valid variable `filter`. `MyComponentWithData` dont have any props, and `props .myParentParam` is not suitable here.

Comment: Then where are you planning to get the first filter value? It has to come from a parent, or it has to be hardcoded, those are your only options. Which means you should set it via `options.variables`.

Comment: I've updated my code example above to better illustrate the approach. `ParentComponent` feeds `ChildComponent` with the initial default filter value, after which `ChildComponent` can refetch with a different parameter once necessary.  

Alternatively the filter value could also be stored in `ParentComponent`'s state, and by passing an `updateFilter(filter)` method to `ChildComponent` you could manipulate it from there.

Comment: Seems variables from `ParentComponent` is only one way with `react-apollo`. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`refetch` accepts a `variables` object as argument, see the [documentation](http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#ObservableQuery.refetch).

Comment: Yes, but before `refetch` will be passed to wrapped component, react-apollo fetch query with "invalid" variables. I need the first request with variables from wrapped component. Not second.